# How to detect the change of a value in an AngularJS table?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am using standard ng-repeat to display some info.

The markup starts like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="p in currentpicks |filter:searchQuery | orderBy:['mcu','psn','litm']" bs-pop>
                                <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
                                <td>{{p.mcu}}</td>
                                <td>
                                    {{p.psn}}
```

I need every time when `p.psn` changes to do something with row styling:

[image]

**Additional Info:** **What i need is that every time the table is created to "catch" the changing p.psn and add styling to define the change.
I just have the data from $http, and i need to discriminate the table rows when a filed changes value.**

How can i do it?

Comment: On big table that would create a lot of expensive watches. How is it being changed? Also, what have you tried?

Comment: See my comment to the answer..When i say "change" i mean that i need to decide on format when i load the data initialy..Then i am not changing anything

Comment: use `ng-class` based on condition in data. Still haven't defined what condition will differentiate styles

Comment: See the additional info that i added, hope it helps

Comment: Still very vague about what is changing and what criteria modifes the style. Need to put more effort into clear and concise explanations

Comment: IMHO your question can be reduced to creating a function in controller  that picks up a change and using this listener to trigger ng-class

Comment: @maioman it may sound simple to you but not me :) how will i detect the change ?

Comment: the change that has to be detected is between the data that's being updated (through maybe $http) and the data collected previously?

Comment: No. I just have the data from $http, and i need to discriminate the table rows when a filed changes value.

Comment: `when a file changes value` ... that is meaningless to us. You have never put the criteria into clear and understandable terms for anyone to provide a proper solution from

Answer (score 1):

```
<tr ng-repeat="p in currentpicks ...." ng-class="{'special': isSpecial(p)}" ....
```

css

```
.special {
  background-color: red;
}
```

script

```
$scope.isSpecial = function(pick) {
      return pick.psn > 1000; //whatever condition
};
```

Comment: less expensive if don't use function ..also needs to be `ng-class` , `class` won't do anything with object

Comment: It is on the right way but can you tell me please how to compare with previous value?

Answer (score 0):

unless you want to write a directive which you then can attach to  html tag in your code, I'd suggest adding a `$watchColletion` to your associated controller:

There is a great example on the angularJs website here:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope

Given that angularJs is a two-way databinding - changes you make to your `currentpicks` collection should automatically be reflected in your view. If they don't, you can always call `$scope.$apply();`

If you want to execute a method when the value changes you can always implement something like this:

```
function myCtrl($scope) {

    $scope.clicks = [];
    $scope.names = ['igor', 'matias', 'misko', 'james'];
    $scope.dataCount = 4;

    $scope.blank = "Hello World";

    $scope.$watchCollection('names', function(newNames, oldNames) {
        if (newNames !== oldNames) {
            $scope.clicks.push(oldNames);
            $scope.dataCount = newNames.length;    
        }
    });

    $scope.doSomething = function(){
        $scope.names.pop();
        $scope.$digest();
    }
}
```

That way you can get right in the middle of your process and execute any custom code you wish.

Fiddler here: https://jsfiddle.net/20p96wv7/

Comment: I may have mislead you ..When i say change i mean on initial data fetch..I am not changing the data after they load...

Comment: Don't try and get into the process, simply apply styling using `ng-class` and let the digest process take care of it for you!

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr ng-class="{'myCssClass': addAwesomeStyle(p.psn, $index)}" ng-repeat="p in currentpicks |filter:searchQuery | orderBy:['mcu','psn','litm']" bs-pop>
                                <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
                                <td>{{p.mcu}}</td>
                                <td>
                                    {{p.psn}}
```

and in your controller:

```
$scope.addAwesomeStyle = function(psn, index){
    var prev = $scope.data[index - 1];

    // compare stuff...
    return true;
}
```

That should sort you out! FWIW I probably wouldn't go about it this way, seems like a bit of a backwards step. I'd go for trying to apply the styling rules up front. That is unless you're going to be changing things on the go!

Comment: I would prefer to apply the things u pfront..But how?

Comment: @e4rthdog really hard to say without understanding how your data is structured and what checks you need to perform. The big issue is that the method will be called per row/per digest which will result in a LOT of calls to the associated expression. Previous poster mentioned that is will be expensive and it will be, especially if your collection is large.

Comment: @MatthewMerryfull this won't work due to the filtering and ordering done to the list by the filters applied in `ng-repeat`.

Comment: @JackA $index is applied based on the rendering, not the filters applied. Inspect source to see the index update when something changes in the underlying collection then rendered.

Comment: @MatthewMerryfull my point is that the `$index` generated by `ng-repeat` will no longer correspond to the index of the original array on the `$scope` once filtering and sorting are applied. See for example: http://jsfiddle.net/8o28t6vn/

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet will be to implement a custom filter that annotates the model with the additional information you need for the UI.

The problem with trying to do something inline is that you need access to the previous item in the list, and the filters you are using prevent you from simply looking at `currentpicks[$index-1]`. Filters get to look at and modify the entire list, so you do have access to the previous item at that point.

The code for your filter would look like this:

```
app.filter("annotateChange", function () {
    return function (list) {
        var lastPsn = list[0].psn;
        for (var i = 0; i < list.length; ++i) {
            if (lastPsn != list[i].psn) {
                list[i].changed = true;
                lastPsn = list[i].psn;
            }
            else {
                list[i].changed = false;
            }
        }
        return list;
    };
});
```

And your markup would change to:

```
<tr ng-repeat="p in currentpicks |filter:searchQuery 
                                 |orderBy:['mcu','psn','litm'] 
                                 |annotateChange" 
    ng-class="{row-changed-class: p.changed}" bs-pop>
    <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
    <td>{{p.mcu}}</td>
    <td>{{p.psn}}</td>
</tr>
```

In this example, `row-changed-class` is the class that gets assigned to the rows where `psn` has changed.

The above code is a simplistic example that has a couple issues you might want to address before putting it into production:

1. The filter currently has no error checking, so if you were to use it on anything other than an array, it would have errors.
2. The filter modifies the original model instances to add the `changed` property. That could be a problem for other users of the model. To avoid this, your filter could be changed to return clones of the original model instances, with the `changed` property added to the clones.
3. The property that you are using to detect changes is currently hard-coded. You might want to modify the filter to pass in the name of the property. This would make it more reusable and easier to change.